# HTML5 Local Storage and Variable Types

Tags: html, variables, types

I was just working on some tests for Local Storage in HTML5. Note I used Safari 6.0.2, as it seems many web-engines handle their methods different.

If I do this:

```
localStorage.setItem('subTotal', Number(12345)); // I know, it's redundant :)
var varType = typeof localStorage.getItem('subTotal');

alert(varType);
```

You would now think; It's a Number!. But no it's not.. It seems, even with type casting, that HTML5 Local Storage converts all variable types to Strings when inserting them. It's funny tho, because when using the Development Tools it shows String values between quotes, but not the Numbers. Maybe it's the Inspector pane that strips the quotes tho.

I already have an old automatic typeCasting function in jQuery, yet I'm always weary of these cases, as 0 and false, can still make a mess of things.

Anyone know if the localStorage.* Library has a setting to maintain the Variable Types?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should convert them to JSON first:

```
localStorage.setItem( 'subTotal', JSON.stringify(12345) );
```

Then, when retrieving your item, parse the JSON:

```
JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('subTotal') );
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hD9dF/

---

For easier usage, create your own wrapper:

```
var myLocalStorage = {
    set: function (item, value) {
        localStorage.setItem( item, JSON.stringify(value) );
    },
    get: function (item) {
        return JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem(item) );
    }
};
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hD9dF/1/

Answer (score 4):

Local storage converts everything to string (as it saves everything as text).
To make your life easier, and at least preserve number/boolean/object structure, `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` everything that goes in and out.

And to improve performance of that suggestion, only use one localStorage variable per "concept" (like all data for a map widget, or all user-preferences, etc), and build a JS object which you then turn into a JSON string, to save to that one variable (when necessary).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is simple with [localDataStorage](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage), where you can transparently set/get any of the following "types": Array, Boolean, Date, Float, Integer, Null, Object or String.

[DISCLAIMER] I am the author of the utility [/DISCLAIMER]

Examples:

```
localDataStorage.set( 'key1', 'Belgian' );
localDataStorage.set( 'key2', 1200.0047 );
localDataStorage.set( 'key3', true );
localDataStorage.set( 'key4', { 'RSK' : [1,'3',5,'7',9] } );
localDataStorage.set( 'key5', null );

localDataStorage.get( 'key1' );   -->   'Belgian'
localDataStorage.get( 'key2' );   -->   1200.0047
localDataStorage.get( 'key3' );   -->   true
localDataStorage.get( 'key4' );   -->   Object {RSK: Array(5)}
localDataStorage.get( 'key5' );   -->   null
```

All of the conversion work is done in the background for you: just set and get.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
let id = JSON.parse(<any>localStorage.getItem("id"))
    
if (typeof id != "number") {
// rest of code
```