# why alert(typeof pageViewCount ); it shows "number", while alert(pageViewCount); it shows "NaN"?

Tags: javascript

The "typeof pageViewCount" shows "number" while the "pageViewCount" shows "NaN",but i don't know why.
And the code is listed as follows.

```
var pageViewCount = localStorage.getItem("pageViewCount");
var pageFirstVisited = localStorage.getItem("pageFirstVisited");
var now = new Date();
if(pageViewCount == null){
    pageViewCount = 0;
    pageFirstVisited = now.toUTCString();
}
var oneMonth = new Date(pageFirstVisited);
oneMonth.setMonth(oneMonth.getMonth()+1);
if(now>oneMonth){
    pageViewCount = 0;
    pageFirstVisited = now.toUTCString();
}
pageViewCount = parseInt("pageViewCount",10)+1;
alert(pageViewCount);
localStorage.setItem("pageViewCount",pageViewCount);
localStorage.setItem("pageFirstVisited",pageFirstVisited);
var output = "You've visited this page " + pageViewCount + " times since" + pageFirstVisited;
document.write(output);
```

Comment: Is that really your question? Or do you want to know what is wrong with your code? Because the problem is that you are trying to parse a text string into a number, which gives you `NaN`. I doubt you even need to parse it in the first place, just do `pageViewCount++;`

Comment: i tried pageViewCount = parseInt(pageViewCount, 10);
 pageViewCount++;          but it still ruturn NaN.

Comment: @legend `console.log(pageViewCount)` before parsing. I bet its undefined

Comment: @Maxx I tried but it had been defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a sting with `parseInt()`

```
pageViewCount = parseInt("pageViewCount",10)+1;
```

You should change it to

```
pageViewCount = parseInt(pageViewCount,10) + 1;
```

Comment: You should not need to parse it at all. It should already be a number

Comment: If you put `alert(pageViewCount)` before `pageViewCount = parseInt(pageViewCount,10)+1`, what do you get?

Comment: @legend: I expect the problem is that you have already allowed a rouge value to be stored in your local storage. you should clear storage and make sure you don't let string get in there. Also, I suggest you change your null check to also check for non-number types too. So you can reset it to 0 if it's not already a valid number

Comment: @musefan - It could be a string representation of a number, e.g. "10" which when added to by +1 would give "101". `parseInt()` will take care of the string to interger conversion.

Comment: @mseifert: Why would it be a string? If OP is using number type for storage then it should be a number. If anything else it means it has been set outside of the intention of the code and should be classed as invalid data anyway.

Comment: I cleared storage and it worked!  I got 0 when launch it. Thanks~

Comment: @musefan - My understanding is that Local storage converts everything to string - at least according to this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442819/html5-local-storage-and-variable-types/13442834)

Comment: @mseifert: yeah looks like you are correct. I thought it gave you the correct type

Comment: @legend - Yes that makes sense. You were storing the NaN value to local storage and clearing the storage was the way to go.

Comment: yeah there's no doubt that Local storage converts everything to string.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, NaN is a numeric datatype value which tells that number value is not computable or showable.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN